# Filter a dictionary using one of multiple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I'm new with Pyhton and would like to filter a dictionary with keys composed by two values. Here my dict:

```
{(0, 'DRYER'): [103.0, 131.0, 9.0, 1.24],
 (2, 'DRYER'): [106.0, 120.0, 5.0, 1.24],
 (2, 'WASHING'): [70.0, 90.0, 11.0, 0.19]}
```

The keys are composed by two values `(n,a)` and I want to create a new dictionary where `n=2`, which results in:

```
{(2, 'DRYER'): [106.0, 120.0, 5.0, 1.24],
 (2, 'WASHING'): [70.0, 90.0, 11.0, 0.19]}
```

If anyone could help, I would be thankful!

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k[0]==2}` could do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if first value of the tuple key is 2, with dict comprehension:

```
{k: v for k, v in dct.items() if k[0]==2}
```

So:

```
In [11]: dct = {(0, 'DRYER'): [103.0, 131.0, 9.0, 1.24],
    ...:  (2, 'DRYER'): [106.0, 120.0, 5.0, 1.24],
    ...:  (2, 'WASHING'): [70.0, 90.0, 11.0, 0.19]}
    ...:  

In [12]: {k: v for k, v in dct.items() if k[0]==2}
Out[12]: 
{(2, 'DRYER'): [106.0, 120.0, 5.0, 1.24],
 (2, 'WASHING'): [70.0, 90.0, 11.0, 0.19]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `filter`

```
new_dict = dict(filter(function(), old_dict.items()))
```

in your case `function()` would be

```
lambda it: True if it[0][0] == 2 else False
```

Basically `filter()` grabs a function and an iterable and removes all the elements from iterable, if the function returns False